# How to Modify/Change a Buddypress/Wordpress Account Activation Process

Tags: buddypress, activation, deactivation

I'm developing a custom BuddyPress/WordPress Plugin. Here's how a user would normally register.

1. A user registers as usual on registration page
2. His/Her account is deactivated till he/she clicks on activation link in his/her email
3. He/She is sent an activation link through the email he/she registered with
4. He/She activates his account by clicking on the link

I'd like to modify **step 4 above** so that even if the user clicks on the activation link, his/her account remains **deactivated** till he/she fills another form on the site for example, a custom survey form. Once this form is filled successfuly, the user can now **be** **activated**.

I'll be programming the custom form myself so that it works the way I want it to, with wordpress/Buddypress actions/filters.

**So my question is**: How can you modify the WordPress/Buddypress activation Process so that the account remains deactivated till the user fill my custom form?

Here's the main action that I intend to use and it fires as soon as the user clicks the buddypress account activation link in their email:

**bp_core_signup_user**

I'll appreciate if someone can point in the right direction on modifying the Buddypress/Wordpress activation process.

Please help. This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Could an acceptable solution put your custom form in step 1, as extra registration questions asked before email confirmation is sent?

Comment: I don't think so. I would like to just modify step 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the bp_core_signup_send_activation_key filter to prevent the activation email being sent as follows

```
add_filter('bp_core_signup_send_activation_key', 'my_bp_core_signup_send_activation_key', 10, 5);

function my_bp_core_signup_send_activation_key($send, $user_id, $user_email, $activation_key, $usermeta) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: There's a shortcut for this type of thing: `add_filter( 'bp_core_signup_send_activation_key', '__return_false' );` - see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_return_false